# How do I detect when output is being redirected?

Tags: winapi, redirect, console-application

I have a Win32 application written in C that can have its console output *via `printf()`* redirected to a log file.

It would be nice if I could have my app detect if it had been started with or without a redirect `>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't possible.  So I'll be reading this to see if I'm wrong...

Comment: No way to know.  I have seen programs that allow for a command line option to do different functionality which is often only turned on when the output is redirected.

Comment: Not 100% sure in Windows, but in Linux there are many programs that behave differently if piped or not... the most common example is "ls".

Comment: Thanks fortran, I forgot to state that I'm coding for Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if my Delphi console app is redirected to a file or pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021916/how-do-i-check-if-my-delphi-console-app-is-redirected-to-a-file-or-pipe)

Comment: @fortran: in fact, the "ls" program from GnuWin32 *does* behave differently if piped just like it does on Linux, so there's definitely a way to get that behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tom, thanks for the input.

I did some experiments and found this works for me..

```
fpost_t pos ;

fgetpos (stdout, & pos) ;
```

When an application's output is being redirected to a file, `fgetpos()` sets `pos` to zero. It makes sense since its freshly opened stderr for you.
**EDIT:** Actually, the value returned may be a positive integer if text has already been redirected to the log/file. So in your code you'd have something like `if (pos >= 0) bfRedirected = TRUE;`

When an application's output is not being redirected - it's going to the console device - not a file, so `fgetpos()` will set `pos` to -1.

Answer (score 2):

I think that pipes are blind by nature, so you don't have a built-in way to tell whether you're being redirected. Moreover, trying to find out what's happening behind an abstraction layer is a bad habit.

**If you really need to control your output, add the log file name as a command line parameter!**

That being said, you can make some smart guesswork to find out:

- A program can query the shell command history to find out the most recent commands executed.
- If you know the path to the logfiles, you can scan that directory and see if a file has been created or changed its size.
- Benchmark writing speed when redirected and not redirected. This would work only if your system is ultra-stable, and environment condition won't change.

Answer (score 2):

The reliable way is to use [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlea) to check the stdout file handle, if it's not redirected then an error will be returned

```
TCHAR chPath[MAX_PATH];
if (GetFinalPathNameByHandle(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), chPath, MAX_PATH, 0))
    std::cout << "stdout redirected to " << chPath << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "stdout not redirected" << '\n';
```

That API is available from Windows Vista onward. On older Windows [`GetMappedFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmappedfilenamea) needs to be used [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/obtaining-a-file-name-from-a-file-handle)

Answer (score 1):

Method from Microsoft: [WriteConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) fails if it is used with a standard handle that is redirected to a file. If an application processes multilingual output that can be redirected, determine whether the output handle is a console handle (one method is to call the [GetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolemode) function and check whether it succeeds).

Answer (score 1):

Example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/isatty?view=msvc-170

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>

int main( void )
{
   if( _isatty( _fileno( stdout ) ) )
      printf( "stdout has not been redirected to a file\n" );
   else
      printf( "stdout has been redirected to a file\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the answer to this is that you can't.  Output redirection works by simply reading the stream of output from a given program and redirecting it to another pipe / stream.  The design of file / streams is such that the writer is ignorant of the reader to the point that you shouldn't know you are being read.

Even detecting that there was a reader would be of no use because there is one in the normal case.  The console is reading the output of your program and displaying it to the screen already.