# How do I check if my Delphi console app is redirected to a file or pipe?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, redirect, delphi-xe

I have a console app that must disable or enable some operations when output is redirected (externally) to a file or pipe (myapp.exe > Foo.bar)

How I can check if my Delphi console app is redirected to a file or pipe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if Console.In (stdin) has been redirected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453220/how-to-detect-if-console-in-stdin-has-been-redirected)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use the [`GetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetFileType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

first you retrieve the console output handle using the GetStdHandle  function and then you can check the type of the handle with the `GetFileType` function.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;


function ConsoleRedirected: Boolean;
var
  FileType : DWORD;
begin
  FileType:= GetFileType(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));
  Result  := (FileType=FILE_TYPE_PIPE) or (FileType=FILE_TYPE_DISK);
end;


begin
  try
    if ConsoleRedirected then
      Writeln('Hello From File')
    else
      Writeln('Hello Console');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: The documentation mentions that `File_Type_Char` is "typically an LPT device or a console," so this method might not tell you when your program's output is being redirected to a printer: `myapp.exe > LPT1`.

Comment: Indeed, but the op ask specifically for `..is redirected to a file or pipe..` so he can use the `Result  := (FileType=FILE_TYPE_PIPE) or (FileType=FILE_TYPE_DISK);
` code which is commented on my answer.

Comment: @RRUZ More likely those were the first two types of redirection that popped into his head. And if that's what you believe then I don't know why you commented out that version.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, answer edited (sorry but I had my mind on many projects at once).

Comment: As usual, @Rob is right on the money. This version will not detect all redirection which is how I interpreted the question. For example `myexe > nul` will result in `FILE_TYPE_CHAR`. Accordingly I will leave my answer here unless somebody can come up with a better way of detecting all forms of redirection.

Answer (score 9):

The approach I present here feels hacky but I can't find a better way to detect whether or not the standard output has been redirected away from a screen console. The approach using `GetFileType` cannot detect all forms of redirection since some redirections are to devices of type `FILE_TYPE_CHAR`.

---

Call [`GetConsoleMode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683167.aspx) passing the standard output handle. If `GetConsoleMode()` fails then your console has been redirected.

```
program RedirectionDetection;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Windows;

function ConsoleRedirected: Boolean;
var
  Mode: DWORD;
begin
  Result := not GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Mode);
end;

begin
  if ConsoleRedirected then begin
    Writeln('I have been redirected');
  end else begin
    Writeln('I am a console');
    Readln;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: what if `GetConsoleMode` fails in console mode due to access rights for example?

Comment: @kobik It's game over if you haven't got access to your own console!!

Comment: what I'm asking is, if this statement is a fact: "If GetConsoleMode() fails then your console has been redirected".

Comment: @kobik It's a well known method for detecting console redirection. Your comment about access rights would apply to any other method of course.

Comment: just to let you know I'm not the down-voter. I just had some doubts about your statement.

Comment: I think this should be better: `Result := not GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Mode) and (GetLastError = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE);`

Comment: @kobik I'm going to leave the answer here until someone can come up with a better way to detect all forms of redirection.