# How to detect I/O-redirection of "stdout" / "sterr" with Windows

Tags: winapi

I need precise Unicode-output to the console. If I imbue wcout to "en_US.UTF8" the characters are mapped to UTF-8 but they arent correctly displayed by the console. So I wrote a little helper function:

```
void writeOutput( wchar_t const *str, bool err )
{
    static mutex      mtx;
    lock_guard<mutex> lock( mtx );
    wstringstream wss;
    wss << str << L"\n";
    wstring strFmt = move( wss.str() );
    DWORD   dwWritten;
    WriteConsoleW( GetStdHandle( !err ?  STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE : STD_ERROR_HANDLE ), strFmt.c_str(), wcslen( strFmt.c_str() ), &dwWritten, nullptr );
}
```

This function correctly displays the Unicode-characters. But if I do I/O-redirection with "program > outfile" nothing is written in the file. So how do I detect that's there a redirection?

Comment: Instead of imbuing UTF-8 locale you should [set UTF-8 in the manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) and use regular i/o.

Comment: On Windows, redirection can usually be detected using `GetFileType()` or `GetConsoleMode()`. There are several questions on StackOverflow that discuss this (in other languages), such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021916/).

Comment: Hi Bonita Montero, you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> So how do I detect that's there a redirection?

As @Remy Lebeau alreay pointed out, [`GetFileType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletype?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function will return `FILE_TYPE_DISK` (The specified file is a disk file.) if console output has been redirected to a file.

The following is how to do in C++:

```
DWORD nType = GetFileType(GetStdHandle(err ? STD_ERROR_HANDLE : STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));
if (FILE_TYPE_DISK == nType)
{
    printf("Output to a disk file.");
}
```